# Why am I seeing banding with Photoshop but not Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, banding

Until the most recent update it used to be the case, at least for me, that I would occasionally see banding in Lightroom's Library module, but not in Photoshop.

With the most recent update, I now see banding in Photoshop but not in Lightroom.

Is this a button or some setting I should change?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the banding you're describing, it will help us identify possible causes.

Comment: I shouldn't but I want to recommend adobe forums.

Answer (score 1):

What you may be seeing is fake banding created by Photoshop. It takes shortcuts to display layered files more quickly that sometime affect the actual appearance of the image on the screen. To check to see if there is actual banding, you can either zoom into the image to 100% or temporarily flatten the image to remove the layers. If what you are seeing is a Photoshop artifact, it should go away under these conditions.

For a very thorough description of banding (including the long version of this explanation) Greg Benz has posted an article on his website. You can find it here:
[No you Really Don't Have Banding in your Photo](https://gregbenzphotography.com/photography-tips/how-to-fix-false-banding-in-the-sky-photoshop)